# How to get the bundle version in Plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I need a reference to the app version in another custom key, how should I refer it ?
I tried `$(BUNDLE_VERSION)` `$(BUNDLE_VERSION_STRING_SHORT)` but nothing yields the value.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$(MARKETING_VERSION)`?

Comment: Agvtool no longer updates marketing version.